# Node.js & EJS 404 Error when Calling delete method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

The issue I am having is I am correctly getting the project ID but when the delete method gets called it just returns a 404 error. Below is the code that is used: 
**Front End**

```
<% for(var i=0; i<projects.length; i++) {%>
              <tr>

                <td>  <%= projects[i].projectName %> </td>
                <td>  <%= projects[i].engineer %> </td>
                <td>  <%= projects[i].finalCost %> </td>
                <td>  <%= projects[i].status %>  </td>
                <td>

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Edit</button>
                  <form method="post" action="/delete/<%=projects[i]._id%>">
                    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
                  </form>
                </td>
              </tr>
                 <%}%>
```

**Backend**:

```
app.delete('/delete/:_id', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.params._id);
var project = {_id: req.params._id};
db.collection('projects').remove({_id: project},(err, result) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)

  console.log('deleted from database')
  res.redirect('/profile')
})
});
```

Comment: Try with res.redirect("back")

Comment: @ŞükranEken that did not fix it, thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 delete form in your ejs file and add `<a href="/delete/<%=projects[i]._id%>"<a>`

Step 2 change app.delete with app.get